# Make root window transparent and also other things accessible

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I want to set my root window transparent, I have done this easily, but I can't move anything in the background of my system, for example my terminal, or anything else.

```py
from tkinter import Tk

self.tk = Tk()
self.tk.attributes('-zoomed', True)  # This just maximizes the window
self.tk.wait_visibility() # just to fix self.tk.attributes
self.tk.attributes('-type', 'dock') # disable title and title buttons
self.tk.attributes('-alpha', 0.1) # transparent
self.tk.mainloop() # main loop
```

The reason I want to do that, is because I want to make an screenshot application, and I want to make some effects that make the system transparent

Comment: ***I can't move anything in the background of my system***: Even if viewable your transparent window overlays the background windows.

Comment: @stovfl Yes I know, so how can I make my windows accessible ?

Comment: ***your transparent window overlays...***: Don't overlay windows you want to move ...

Answer (score 0):

You could make any color completly transparent in your window.

```
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

root.configure(bg='white')
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white')
root.attributes('-topmost', True)

root.mainloop()
```

I think code speaks for itself. (OS dependent, works on windows)

Comment: bad attribute `"-transparentcolor"`, There is no such attribute `transparentcolor`.

Comment: @Bar Did you try my code in separate module and it didn't work, or are you trying to modify your code with attributes? I tested this code it works fine.

Comment: I ran my code exactly like you, What python version are you using ? I'm using python3.8.2

Comment: @Bar I am guessing you are using Linux or Mac. I just read that code above is OS dependent.